# What algorithm / data structure for managing exclusion on a given set of feature options?

Tags: algorithms

Imagine I have to manage products.
Products have features , features maybe have free input option, or set of limited options,
not all the  probabilities will be available:

```
 options01/features01 *  options02/features02 * ...  options0n/features0n
```

so I have a set of rules where on 
specific condition on a feature:
blacklists/whitelist a set or range of options for another feature

(e.g on select featureA full set of option for FeatureB will be disabled/enable accordingly to rules FeatureA->FeatureB)

Simpler approach would be to determine a priority for rules based on Features, so if I have

```
FeatureA, FeatureB and FeatureC , 
rulesA->rulesB->rulesC
rulesB->rulesC 
(but not: rulesB->rulesA , rulesC->rulesB, RulesC->rulesA)
```

But what if I don't have a priority list of rules, so basically any change to any feature option will affect other feature.

Is there any Algorithm to manage this problem? what would be a practical data structure to store information about feature options and listing rules?

Comment: I think, you are asking for a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph

Comment: Also, see [State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), [Decision Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)